# PHP execute after specific CSS (WordPress function?)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, css

I am using infinite scroll and would like to post an image after every 3 times an article is loaded. Preferably a WordPress function would be best. Can anyone direct me to an article which covers this or perhaps offer a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem, a good solution is AJAX.
Once an article is loaded, call a JS function which call your Wordpress function.
I am not a Wordpress expert but AJAX is an hint to achieve that.